# SQL Server Nested object with FOR JSON PATH

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

```
{
    "dnaSequences": [
        {
            "id": "seq_fdfdfd",
            "fields": {
                "ORF": [
                    "seq_aaaaaa",
                    "seq_bbbbbbbb",
                    "seq_ccccccccc",
                    "seq_ddddddddd"
                ]
            },
            "isCircular": false,
            "schemaId": "ts_fdfdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to create this JSON above with the FOR JSON PATH in SQL Server...

This is the query so far...but i cant seem to get the double quotes correct around the nested objects in the ORF array? Also the values in the ORF are comping from one field in multiple records.

```
SELECT top 1 id,
       (SELECT top 3 orf_seq_xxx AS 'fields.ORF'
        FROM vw_viewName
        FOR JSON PATH) AS ORF,
       [isCircular],
       [schemaId]
FROM vw_viewNameFOR JSON PATH, ROOT('dnaSequences');
```

field:  orf_seq_xxx   is created in a sql view by concatenating data together..

```
SUBSTRING((SELECT top 5 ',' + 'seq_aaaaa_' AS 'data()'FROM [v_viewName] FOR XML PATH('')), 2 , 9999)As orf_seq_xxx
```

you can ignore the top 5  and the top 3 in the sql...I only have this to limit the amount of data..

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I included the code attempts?  The current query is my code attempts..  I will create a sql fiddle...

Comment: I keep trying to create a sql fiddle with this

```
CREATE TABLE TblName1
    ([id] varchar(25), [orf_seq_xxx] varchar(max),[isCircular] varchar(10), [schemaId] varchar(75))
;

INSERT INTO TblName1
    ([id], [orf_seq_xxx],[isCircular],[schemaId])
VALUES
    ( 'seq_aaaaaa', 'seq_aaaaaa,seq_aaaaaa,seq_aaaaaa,seq_aaaaaa,seq_aaaaaa', 'false', 'ts_aaaaa1' ),
   ( 'seq_bbbbbb', 'seq_bbbbbb,seq_bbbbbb,seq_bbbbbb,seq_bbbbbb,seq_bbbbbb', 'false', 'ts_bbbbb1' ),
   ( 'seq_cccccc', 'seq_cccccc,seq_cccccc,seq_cccccc,seq_cccccc,seq_cccccc', 'false', 'ts_ccccc1' )
;

```

Comment: I get this error every time
Database 'db_18_e5c1bd' already exists. Choose a different database name.

Comment: My sql server version for this one is sql 2017 and sql 2019

Comment: The desired output is the first thing I put in my question...

Comment: It would be a lot easier to deal with the base tables rather than the view

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1670/4

Comment: I was able to create a sql fiddle

Comment: Basically All I need is the json to look like my example at the top of question...  I need double quotes around the values in    "ORF": [    array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest `fields.ORF` in a subquery.

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support `JSON_AGG`, which would have made things simpler. Instead we need to hack it with `STRING_AGG` (to aggregate), `STRING_ESCAPE` (to escape quotes) and `JSON_QUERY` (to prevent double-escaping).

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  [fields.ORF] = JSON_QUERY((
      SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(s.value, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.orf_seq_xxx, ',') s
  )),
  isCircular = CASE WHEN t.isCircular = 'true' THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END,
  t.schemaId
FROM TblName1 t
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('dnaSequences');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/159589)

Doing this using the base tables, rather than having to split and re-aggregate, would be easier and certainly more performant. If you were querying the base table you would probably have something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  [fields.ORF] = JSON_QUERY(
      '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(t.orf_seq_xxx, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'
  ),
  isCircular = CASE WHEN t.isCircular = 'true' THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END,
  t.schemaId
FROM BaseTable t
GROUP BY
  t.id,
  t.isCircular,
  t.schemaId
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('dnaSequences');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243634/discussion-on-answer-by-charlieface-sql-server-nested-object-with-for-json-path).